# Will a NA PSN cd key work in other region?

Tags: ps4, psn, star-wars-battlefront

Ive been offered to buy a CD key of a PS4 game, but the key is from NA (North America) and me and my account are from Argentina.
Will it work anyways?
And if it works, will I be able to play online despite the region Im in?
Thank you.

Comment: For what it is worth PS4 does not use region restrictions what so ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work, but you'll have to use a workaround for these kind of situations ;)

While the PS4 can play any physical game (on disc) without a problem, the redeemable codes (like the CD key you're talking about and DLC) are region locked. You won't be able to redeem a North American key on a European account / in the EU PSN Store.

The good news is that you can easily create an account for the region that the key is for! If you want to redeem a NA key, just create a new Playstation account with fake credentials and the right region (NA in this case). Be aware that DLC will only work with games from the same region.

The source for this is [the official statement from Sony's PS4 FAQ](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/30/ps4-the-ultimate-faq-north-america/):

> "Do PS4 games have regional locks? In general, neither digital nor
>   disc-based games will be region locked, but PlayStation recommends
>   that all users purchase games at the region of their residence to
>   guarantee the best overall experience and customer service. In certain
>   instances, a software publisher may choose to region lock a game title
>   for specific reasons, but Sony Computer Entertainment expects these
>   instances to be uncommon."